# Where to get godef binary?

Tags: go

I'm trying to install godef binary using the command:

```
go get -v code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef
```

However it keeps giving me error:

```
package code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/cmd/godef: unable to detect version control system for code.google.com/ path
```

How do I install godef binary?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The current source for godef is at https://github.com/rogpeppe/godef. Use the following command to install godef:

```
go get github.com/rogpeppe/godef
```

Comment: As an aside, if you're using this to setup a dev environment, know that this installs the `godef` binary in `DIR/bin/`, where DIR is the first entry in your GOPATH. make sure that the corresponding `DIR/bin` is also part of your shell's `PATH`. I had it already installed it in another folder covered by GOPATH (but outside my PATH), and `go get` is a no-op in that case.